# PHP - Google Analytics API - Using variables in data_ga->get

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm having a little trouble with Google Analytics and asking it to provide results based on a variable containing a date rather than a date as a plain string.

**Declaration of variables:**

```
$date = new DateTime();
$end_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');

$date = sub(new DateInterval('P1M'));
$start_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

**Code:**

```
function getResults($analytics, $profileId) {
return $analytics->data_ga->get('ga:'.$profileId, $start_date, $end_date, 'ga:sessions');
}
```

The variables are assigned elsewhere; but when I run the code I'm getting the following:

> There was a general error : (get) missing required params: 'start-date', 'end-date'

Anyone know why, when using them as plain strings with single quotes works? (e.g: '2014-09-04 for today)

Comment: Seems like both variables aren't defined.  Could you attach more code?

Comment: @osowskit Just checked the error logs. You're right, the log says the variables aren't defined... Strange. (They are defined at the top)

Comment: Can you paste the whole file?

Comment: @CyrilleArmanger It's okay. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had a moment of inspiration. I realised that my "Code" was inside a function. It made sense that the variables had to be passed to the function for the code to understand it.

**Fixed Code**

```
function runMainDemo($analytics, $start_date, $end_date) 
{ 
try 
{ 
$profileId = getFirstProfileId($analytics); 
if (isset($profileId)) 
{ 
$results = getResults($analytics, $profileId, $start_date, $end_date);
...
}
...
}
...
}

function getResults($analytics, $profileId, $start_date, $end_date) {
return $analytics->data_ga->get('ga:'.$profileId, $start_date, $end_date, 'ga:sessions');
}
```

Comment: I have the exact same code block and it does not work, "missing required param. end-date. Must be a bug.

Comment: @user734063 did you try:

`function runMainDemo($analytics, $start_date, $end_date) {
  try {
    $profileId = getFirstProfileId($analytics);

    if (isset($profileId)) {
      $results = getResults($analytics, $profileId, $start_date, $end_date);`?

I found you need to pass it through the runMainDemo function as well as the getResults function. (If you're following the same Google Analytics Example I did)